# C# StreamReader reading from textfile missing the first line

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader

My streamReader is reading my textfile from a specific location but it only reads 9 lines instead of 10 lines , the textfile consists of 10 lines , what gone wrong here? Its omitting the first line and display only the rest of the 9 lines.

Here is my code :

```
  using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath(@daoWordPuzzle.GetfileURL())))
       {
           foreach (var line in reader.ReadLine())
           {
               Response.Write(reader.ReadLine() + " <br />");
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   using (StreamReader reader = 
      File.OpenText(Server.MapPath(@daoWordPuzzle.GetfileURL())))
   {
       //reader.ReadLine returns a string
       //so here you are iterating the first line of the file
       //this means line is a char
       foreach (var line in reader.ReadLine())
       {
           Response.Write(reader.ReadLine() + " <br />");
       }
   }
```

What you should be doing is:

```
   using (StreamReader reader = 
      File.OpenText(Server.MapPath(@daoWordPuzzle.GetfileURL())))
   {
       string line;
       while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           Response.Write(line + " <br />");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Spender covered why your loop is not working and I suggest a cleaner method [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx). This will load the lines into memory as they are read, so it has low overhead.

Try:

```
string path = Server.MapPath(@daoWordPuzzle.GetfileURL());

foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(path))
{
    Response.Write(line + " <br />");
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain why this works and why the OP's didn't.
I like this solution better than @Spender's because it's cleaner - no messy while loops and variable assignments.

Comment: @m.t.bennett I made reference to spender's solution since I don't think it needs to be repeated.